# Get issuerNameHash and issuerKeyHash of x509

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, certificate, public-key

I need to get the following out of x509 CA certificates:

- the Hash of the DER encoded public key (excluding tag and length) of the subject public key field
- the hash of the issuers distinguished name, that must be calculated over the DER encoding of the issuer's name field

I tried to use `X509_issuer_name_hash` and `X509_pubkey_digest` , but apparently they return not the results that I expect.

This question and the answers posted is close to what I look for: [How can I get issuerNameHash and issuerKeyHash from PEM or DER certificates?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87661/how-can-i-get-issuernamehash-and-issuerkeyhash-from-pem-or-der-certificates) but I would like to have an explanation on how to do this in C++ and OpenSSL.

**UPDATE:** X509_pubkey_digest is exactly what i needed, I just made a mistake converting to hexstring. The hash of the issuer's distinguished name is still open though.